# graphics programming

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction

I would like to program some graphic figures such as line, circle,etc. I have used turboc++ 3.0 for
dos graphics. I would like to do the same with the compilers dev c++ or code blocks or vc++.

I would like to implement dda and bresenhems line and circle drawing algorithm.
how should I go about implementing these programs through these compilers (not the command line tools).

I have a really vague picture of graphics programming.please help..

please note : I  have a nvidia graphics card 1gb.. so I cannot use dos graphics (I think the card is the reason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're wanting to play around with graphics code to draw objects and do things with them may I suggest that you skip the whole Windows/GDI/DirectX/ thing completely and take a look at [Processing](http://processing.org/)?

It's basically Java, so you won't have to jump too far for the language, but more specifically it's designed for playing around and experimenting with graphics, so may suit you perfectly.

Comment: processing that's what i was looking For Thanks cruachan . \m/

Answer (score 3):

You really have a vast variety of options. Starting from [GDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface) (not hardware accelerated), finishing with a heavy stuff like [DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX), [OpenGl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opengl). There is also a nice library, called [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer). It does not really matter what technology you will use to solve your problems. If the speed is not a matter, i think GDI is the right and most simple choice.

Comment: will i be able to program scan line algorithms

Comment: Of course you will. I personally programmed scanline algorithm using GDI. Basically, you will need only one graphics function - for drawing a single pixel.Using libraries like DirectX and OpenGl you wouldn't even have to program such low level things.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start off with these tutorials:

http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/C-and-Cpp/Graphics/1

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of things, you're trying to produce a program that runs on Windows. In that case, you don't need to implement basics like Bresenham's algorithm to be able to draw lines and circles. Windows provides `MoveTo` and `LineTo` to do basic line drawing, and `Ellipse` to draw ellipses -- and if the axes are equal, the ellipse it draws will be a circle.

Edit: It also sounds like you haven't written any code for Windows. This is *quite* different from writing code for DOS, so you'll probably need a good book. Charles Petzold's *Programming Windows* is a classic (though for C++ you'll want a somewhat older version -- I believe the current ones concentrate on the .NET languages).

Answer (score 0):

I am using the powerful cross platform project: http://cimg.sourceforge.net/ .
you have there all primitives and more.
I you wish to use your GPU power you can use glut library for OpenGL.

cheers Arman.

Comment: the link you have  provided is a bad link.

Comment: @PVB: what is bad with that?you don't like the content? or what?the link is the CImg project web page hosted on sourceforge.net .

Comment: @Turtle: Thanks for explanation, but the link is not broken. I just checked it is ok.